# how to fill multiple nulls next to not null value in a column with LAG function? pls suggest

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, lag

I want to fill nulls in a Date column with the previous value to them i.e 12-01-2016 as i can give defenite offset values ,but in case 1 have more than 2 nulls then how it could be done?

```
select id,coalesce(date,lag(date,1)over(partition by id order by fromdt),
                    lag(date,2)over(partition by id order by fromdt)
from abc
```

Present data

```
ID DATE       FROMDT      TODT
1  12-01-2015 15-01-2015  20-01-2015
2  12-01-2016 01-01-2016  20-02-2016
3  NULL       21-02-2016  22-02-2016
4  NULL       23-02-2016  24-02-2016
```

Expected Data

```
ID DATE           FROMDT      TODT
1  12-01-2015    15-01-2015  20-01-2015
2  12-01-2016    01-01-2016  20-02-2016
3  12-01-2016    21-02-2016  22-02-2016
4  12-01-2016    23-02-2016  24-02-2016
```

Comment: the `lag` values don't propagate. You'll have to join or apply the data to itself instead, to find the first record that matches with a value.

Comment: thanks .. do we have any other way to get it done with case or something..

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support the `IGNORE NULL`s option on window functions.  One option is to assign a "grouping" and then spread the value over the group:

```
select t.*, max(date) over (partition by grp) as imputed_date
from (select t.*,
             count(date) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are *strictly* in ascending order then you can use a `MAX` window aggregate

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  ISNULL([date], MAX([date]) OVER (ORDER BY FROMDT ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))
FROM abc;
```